# Can you jump over a Junkrat trap?

Tags: overwatch

I've started playing Sombra a lot more, and I ran into this on Route 66. I attempted to jump over a trap, but I got caught in it anyway. I was even invisible and moving faster than usual.

Is it possible to jump over a Junkrat trap without it triggering, with any character?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No characters can jump high enough.

Overwatch hitboxes have ben proven to work by radius (sphere) on many occasions, so junkrat trap should work the same. You would have to jump [1 meter high](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Junkrat#Steel_Trap) to clear it. And all characters jump less than that to my knowledge.

Characters who can rocket jump / float can of course clear it (Rocket jumping taking more skill of course)

Comment: I suppose a Pharah could hover over it, but that's unfortunate. I guess Junkrat needs all the help he can get though.